# EKCalendarChooser delegate not working from within NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, ekcalendar

I have an NSObject class that consists of a basic EKCalendarChooser implementation and I am unable to get the delegate functions `calendarChooserDidFinish`, `calendarChooserSelectionDidChange`, and `calendarChooserDidCancel` working. I'm not sure if it is the fact that everything is in an NSObject but I wanted to keep this code separate from my other files.

I've tried a lot of troubleshooting such as not keeping the delegate methods under an extension and even making a global variable for the EKCalendarChooser as I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087957/nsobject-not-calling-delegates-of-other-classes) which states that non-global items could be dereferenced in contexts like this. Overall I can get the controller to pop up and it's just the way I want, but the delegate methods don't work. Below is the entire code and in my main viewController I get this to show with   `AddAppointments(parentViewController: self).chooseCalendarTapped()`

```
import UIKit
import EventKitUI

class Cal: NSObject {
    
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    var parentViewController: UIViewController
    var CalendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser = EKCalendarChooser()
    
    init(parentViewController: UIViewController) {
           self.parentViewController = parentViewController
           super.init()
    }
   

  func chooseCalendarTapped() {
        let authStatus = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
        
        switch authStatus {
        case .authorized:
            showCalendarChooser()
        case .notDetermined:
            requestAccess()
        case .denied:
            // Explain to the user that they did not give permission
            break
        case .restricted:
            break
        @unknown default:
            preconditionFailure("Who knows what the future holds ")
        }
    }
    
    func requestAccess() {
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                // may not be called on the main thread..
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showCalendarChooser()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showCalendarChooser() {
        CalendarChooser = EKCalendarChooser(selectionStyle: .single, displayStyle: .allCalendars, entityType: .event, eventStore: eventStore)
        
        // customization
        CalendarChooser.showsDoneButton = true
        CalendarChooser.showsCancelButton = true
        
        // dont forget the delegate
        CalendarChooser.delegate = self
        
        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CalendarChooser)
        parentViewController.present(nvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    
}

extension Cal : EKCalendarChooserDelegate {
    func calendarChooserDidFinish(_ calendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser) {
        print(calendarChooser.selectedCalendars)
     //   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func calendarChooserSelectionDidChange(_ calendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser) {
        print("Changed selection")
    }
    
    func calendarChooserDidCancel(_ calendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser) {
        print("Cancel tapped")
     //   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not shown how your view controller hooks into that class. I see a danger of a retain cycle here. Or, just the other way, maybe you are releasing this object too soon. Please provide more context.

Comment: For example, you might be saying `Cal().chooseCalendarTapped()` or similar — which means the Cal object pops up the calendar chooser but then goes out of existence and cannot serve as delegate. How do we _know_ you are not making that mistake? We don't, if you don't show the code. You need to _prove_ to us that you're doing this right (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works now:

Declaring a var at the controller class level works here instead of having a new instance inside a function:

**Controller**:

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    var event = EventManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        event.chooseCalendarTapped(presentingVC: self)
    }
}
```

**EventManager Class**:

```
import UIKit
import EventKitUI

class EventManager: NSObject {
    
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    override init() {
           super.init()
       }
    
    weak var delegate: EKCalendarChooserDelegate? = nil
    
    var presentingVC: UIViewController? = nil
    

    func chooseCalendarTapped(presentingVC: UIViewController) {
        
        self.presentingVC = presentingVC
        
        let authStatus = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
        
        switch authStatus {
        case .authorized:
            showCalendarChooser()
        case .notDetermined:
            requestAccess()
        case .denied:
            // Explain to the user that they did not give permission
            break
        case .restricted:
            break
        @unknown default:
            preconditionFailure("Who knows what the future holds ")
        }
    }
    
    func requestAccess() {
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                // may not be called on the main thread..
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showCalendarChooser()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showCalendarChooser() {
        let vc = EKCalendarChooser(selectionStyle: .single, displayStyle: .allCalendars, entityType: .event, eventStore: eventStore)
        
        // customization
        vc.showsDoneButton = true
        vc.showsCancelButton = true
        
        // dont forget the delegate
        vc.delegate = self
        
        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        
        presentingVC?.present(nvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension EventManager: EKCalendarChooserDelegate {
    func calendarChooserDidFinish(_ calendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser) {
        print(calendarChooser.selectedCalendars)
        presentingVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func calendarChooserSelectionDidChange(_ calendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser) {
        print("Changed selection")
    }
    
    func calendarChooserDidCancel(_ calendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser) {
        print("Cancel tapped")
        presentingVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only is not useful. Please provide, as part of the answer, an explanation of how this code is different from the OPs and why that would fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: This got it working, I really can’t thank you enough!